# Registering UITableViewCell using ReusableKit swift

Tags: swift, generics

I am trying to build generic `getAll` method will which just return instances of Reusable cells.
By creating that I don't have to register the cells manually I can just add it to the array and in the `registerCellsFromReusable()` it will be registered.

```swift
enum Reusable {
    static let listOptionTableCell = ReusableCell<ListOptionTableCell>(nibName: "ListOptionTableCell")
    static let seperatorTableCell = ReusableCell<SeperatorTableCell>(nibName: "SeperatorTableCell")
    
    static func getAll<T>() -> [ReusableCell<T>] where T : UITableViewCell {
        return [listOptionTableCell, seperatorTableCell]
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    registerCellsFromReusable()
}

private func registerCellsFromReusable() {
    Reusable.getAll().forEach { tableView.register($0) }
}
```

Cool stuff but I don't know why I am getting the below issue even though `ListOptionTableCell` & `SeperatorTableCell` inherits from `UITableViewCell`

[image]

Note: I am using [ReusableKit](https://github.com/devxoul/ReusableKit) to do this.

Comment: You get this error because swift is unable to create array like this. `Reusable<ListOptionTableCell>` is a different type than `Reusable<SeparatorTableCell>`. The solution for this is to find the closest common denominator (`UITableViewCell)` of these to types, and "erase" them to this type.

Comment: @SanderSaelmans can you please show practically what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I have no in depth knowledge of the `ReusableKit` framework, but in order to make this work you have to apply some form of type erasure. Swift is unable to create a properly typed collection of different types (due to the generics used here), so we have to find a type to which we can convert them to match your needs. In this case, this would be `ReusableCell<UITableViewCell>`. We only care that `T` in ReusableCell inherits from `UITableViewCell` in the end.

```swift
// Create an extension on ReusableCell to type erase it
extension ReusableCell {
    var asTypeErasedReusableCell: ReusableCell<UITableViewCell> {
        ReusableCell<UITableViewCell>(nibName: nibName)
    }
}

enum Reusable {
    static let listOptionTableCell = ReusableCell<ListOptionTableCell>(nibName: "ListOptionTableCell")
    static let seperatorTableCell = ReusableCell<SeperatorTableCell>(nibName: "SeperatorTableCell")
    
    static func getAll() -> [ReusableCell<UITableViewCell>] {
        [
            listOptionTableCell.asTypeErasedReusableCell, 
            seperatorTableCell.asTypeErasedReusableCell
        ]
    }
}
```

Note that this is a very simple implementation of type erasure. There are way more sophisticated ways of achieving this.